# How do I maximize the following?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, number-theory

I want to maximize

$${T(\epsilon)=\max\left\{\log_{(1/y)}\left(|\sqrt{2}-x/y|\right):x,y\in\mathbb{N}, |\sqrt{2}-x/y|<\epsilon\right\}}$$

**Edit:** I changed the inequality, it was supposed to be greater than

**Edit 2**: Perhaps it should be less than

When I used my code I tried (for $\epsilon=.0001$)

```
NMaximize[{x, y} \[Element] Integers && Log[1/y, Sqrt[2] - x/y] && 
  RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]<= .0001, {x, y}]
```

But instead I get:

```
NMaximize::nnum: The function value -False is not a number at {x,y} = {0.918621,0.716689}.

NMaximize::nnum: The function value -False is not a number at {x,y} = {0.918621,0.716689}.

NMaximize::nnum: The function value -False is not a number at {x,y} = {0.918621,0.716689}.
```

How do we fix this and create $T(\epsilon)$ in my code.

Comment: Are you sure about changing the inequality to be ">" ?  That removes a very small fraction of all possible pairs of values.

Comment: @JimB You’re probably right. I did you the less than sign in a previous edit. Do you know why no one is answering? How difficult is this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) that you intended to try should be `NMaximize[{f, constraints}, {x, y}]`. But unfortunately

```
NMaximize[{
  Log[1 / y, Abs[Sqrt[2] - x / y]],
  Element[{x, y}, Integers] && x >= 1 && y >= 2 && Abs[Sqrt[2] - x / y] < 0.0001
}, {x, y}]
```

gives a warning like

```
NMaximize::incst: NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints ...
```

and you would get an answer that does not satisfy the given constraints.

As an alternative option: my guess is that $y$ should be small as possible to maximize your expression (I hope this is correct or at least works as an approximation). For this purpose, you can use [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html). The following function returns a triplet $\{T(\epsilon),x,y\}$ for a given $\epsilon$.

```
t[eps_] := Module[{r, x, y},
  r = Rationalize[Sqrt[2], eps];
  x = Numerator[r];
  y = Denominator[r];
  {Log[1/y, Abs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]], {x, y}}
];
```

Example:

```
Table[{10^-n, t[10^-n]}, {n, 1, 10}] // N
```

[image]

Comment: Because `1` cannot be a base of logarithm, it must be `y>1` in the above.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for pointing it out! I changed it to `y >= 2` (and Mathematica gave me a wrong result).

Answer (score 3):

Since the feasible discrete set `RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x / y] < 0.0001` is infinite, this is a hard task for `NMaximize`. It can be done as follows. First, we find the maximum for `x >= 1000 && y >= 1000` by

```
NMaximize[{Log[1/y, RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]], 
Element[{x, y}, Integers] && x >= 1000 && y >= 1000 && 
RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y] < 0.0001}, {x, y},Method->{"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" ->3}]
```

which produces `{1.51158, {x -> 1649, y -> 1166}}` and a warning

> NMaximize::incst: NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {-0.0001+RealAbs[Sqrt[2]-Round[x]/Round[<<1>>]]<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution.

The above result is a feasible solution in view of

```
N[RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y] /. { x -> 1649, y -> 1166}]
```

> `0.0000231443`

Second, in order to be sure, we apply the known lower estimate for `RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]` (see the "Liouville numbers and transcendence" section in [that Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence) for info) $$\exists A>0\, \forall\{x,y\}\in\mathbb{N} \left| \sqrt{2}-\frac{x}{y}\right|> \frac A {y^2} $$. According to Lemma from this section, we may take $A=\frac 1 {5}$ ($M=5$). This inequality implies the inequality  `ForAll[{x,y},{x,y} \[Element] PositiveIntegers && y>1, Log[1/y, RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]] < Log[1/y, 1/5] + 2]`. It is clear the maximum of  `Log[1/y, 1/5] + 2]` for all integers `y >=1000`  is attained at `y==1000` and is equal to `N[Log[1/1000, 1/5]]==0.23299`.

Third, now we apply counting for `x>=1&&x<=999&&y>=2&&y<=999`

```
Do[If[RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y] < 0.0001, Print[{x, y, N[Log[1/y, RealAbs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]]]}]],
 {x, 1, 999}, {y, 2, 999}]
```

> `{99,70,2.24473} {140,99,2.07542}... {997, 705, 1.59229}`

Summarizing the above, we draw the conclusion that the maximum under consideration is equal to  `2.224473` at `{x==99,y==70}`.

Edit. `1000` in the above instead of `100` and constant $A= \frac 1 5$ instead of $A=\frac 1 3$.

Comment: It should be `2.24473` instead of `2.224473` in the last but one line of my answer. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment.  Many times constructing a figure helps one focus on a solution.  Below the gray dots are the values of `Log[1/y, Abs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]]`, the green dots are the values where `Abs[Sqrt[2] - x/y] <= 0.0001`, and the red dot is where the maximum for x>=1&&x<=300&&y>=2&&y<=300 occurs.

```
ϵ = 1/10000;
t = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Log[1/y, Abs[Sqrt[2] - x/y]]}, {x, 1, 300}, {y, 2,  300}], 1];

t0 = Select[t, Abs[Sqrt[2] - #[[1]]/#[[2]]] < ϵ &];
(* {{99, 70, -(Log[99/70 - Sqrt[2]]/Log[70])}, 
    {140, 99, -(Log[-(140/99) + Sqrt[2]]/Log[99])}, 
    {198, 140, -(Log[99/70 - Sqrt[2]]/Log[140])},
    {239, 169, -(Log[-(239/169) + Sqrt[2]]/Log[169])},
    {280, 198, -(Log[-(140/99) + Sqrt[2]]/Log[198])},
    {297, 210, -(Log[99/70 - Sqrt[2]]/Log[210])}} *)

tmax = Select[t0, #[[3]] == Max[t0[[All, 3]]] &]
(* {99, 70, -(Log[99/70 - Sqrt[2]]/Log[70])} *)

ListPointPlot3D[{t, t0, tmax}, SphericalRegion -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  RotationAction -> "Clip", ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Gray, PointSize[0.001]}, {Green, PointSize[0.01]}, {Red, PointSize[0.015]}}]
```

[image: 3D plot of candidate points satisfying constraints]

Comment: To be exact, you should write "where the maximum for `x>=1&&x<=300&&y>=2&&y<=300`   occurs" instead of "where the maximum occurs". Let us call things by their proper names.

Comment: @user64494 Changed.  I appreciate the comment.